# Navigation algorithm

Tags: navigation, robotics

I am working on an autonomous boat able to sail across a given route, mapped as an array of waypoints.

The robot runs several nodes (threads) handling navigation and performing sensor fusion, one of those being the Path Planner.
The on-board computer, a  Raspberry Pi, has stored several terrain profile maps (GIS altitude datasets) shaped as squares and listed in a map as upper corner lat/lon and lower lat/lon. The idea is to avoid groundings and coastlines while passing through the waypoints in the given route.

Basically every X seconds the path planner checks the boat GPS position and finds in which region it is located to load the corresponding map and define the best route (adding intermediate waypoints) using an artificial potential field navigation system; the computation is dynamically performed once for every region.
Despite being quite lightweight (the path planner is run once a while, as it takes 75% processor power to perform calculations), this approach comes with two main drawbacks:

1. The map regions may overlap and the boat will have troubles deciding which map to load;
2. There may be the case where the last intermediate waypoint falls on the edge of a region, so the robot will be "blind" while a path planner update is triggered and a new intermediate route calculated.

Do you have any idea on how to define a better algorithm? Thank you

Comment: Do you have to work with regions? If you know an approximate route in advance, you could pre-process the map data to select on those elements that have some chance of being relevant. Depth information is usually only important close to the coast, for example. If you can reduce the data set size to something that can be worked on all at once, I think a lot of these problems will go away. I'm not suggesting that is necessarily an easy task, of course. Incidentally, how are you dealing with wind/tides?

Comment: Depth info files are loaded according to the overall route, but almost everywhere there are small islands or shallow waters to stay away from and on a huge route the pre-processing is too much for a Pi. For the wind I use the same approach, but the datasets are downloaded in real-time

Comment: I wasn't suggesting pre-processing on the Pi. I was suggesting that perhaps you could turn your large dataset into something more Pi-friendly before the voyage. If you can't, then if you probably is the handling of region edge, perhaps you could recompute a region dynamically, such that the region centre was your current location? You'd have to merge a number of tiles, possibly dealing with the overlaps. I don't know how often you'd have to do this -- I guess it depends on the vessel's speed and the density of hazards -- but you'd always have a map tile that covered the imminent hazards.

Comment: I have three types of path planner, a _static nagivator_ using depth datasets, a _semi-static module_ to take into account wind and AIS boats headings and finally a _dynamic one_ for the imminent collision (just steers the boat). Now of the three only the static navigator could be pre-computed, which would give me quite a very huge map if I take a route of thousands of miles for instance. The datasets are unfortunately downloaded as square regions with a fixed width and lenght so I don't see it possible to create regions dynamically.